# Refer a particular sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to search a particular Worksheet(Say "FebData") in all opened workbooks provided name of all workbooks totally depends on the user(it can be anything).To be honest by googling and putting some efforts form my side as well i got this code.

```
Dim wbSearch As Workbook, wsSearch As Worksheet, wsFind As Worksheet
Dim name As String
Dim j As String
name = InputBox("Enter your Sheet Name, You are searching for.")
If Len(name) = 0 Then 'Checking if Length of name is 0 characters
MsgBox "Please enter a valid name!", vbCritical
Else
j = name
End If
' to search a worksheet in all opened worksheets
For Each wbSearch In Application.Workbooks
    For Each wsSearch In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        if wsFInd = j then 
        worksheet("j").activate
        else
    Next wsSearch
Next wbSearch
end if
```

At last i want to add a feature which i don't have any idea about how to write a code for that, is if two worksheets of same name(Input from user) are present just pop up a msgbox "Duplicate sheet found".

Comment: Are you going to reply to the answers?

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through the workbooks and then loop through each sheet

```
    Sub LoopBks()

    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
            For Each sh In wb.Sheets
                If sh.Name = "FebData" Then
                    MsgBox "Sheets found in..." & wb.Name
                End If
            Next sh
        End If
    Next wb

End Sub
```